# How to use DCA to deduce the contacts between 2 proteins ensembles?

Tags: sequence-analysis

I would like to use [DCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_coupling_analysis) (direct coupling analysis) to analyze the interface between 2 protein ensembles (how the 2 ensembles interacts). Do you have access to a tutorial on this matter? A source code?

I found [this](https://github.com/carlobaldassi/GaussDCA.jl) Julia library and [this](http://stanford.edu/~jesszhao/files/pydcaPresentation.pdf) library by stanford, but I am not sure if it's the right way to go and how to use these 2 for a simple test case of binding between a $\text{Ca}^{2+}$/calmodulin and a [CaMKII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ca2%2B/calmodulin-dependent_protein_kinase_II).